# REST for ecommerce site

Tags: rest, e-commerce, rpc

I am looking at the creation of a large ecommerce portal that can be used to select items, update quantity, place orders, and ask the shipper to pick up items.
A lot of this is transactional in nature like billing, payment, shipping etc.

RPC approaches seem to be the traditional way of doing such distributed processing.

I am new to REST, and I know the basics.
What scenarios can REST be used in a large transactional ecommerce portal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes REST would definitely benefit you.

I think you should check this doc by Alexandros Marinos http://docs.google.com/View?id=ddffwdq5_2csz22wfd&pageview=1&hgd=1, he explains in details of using RESTful transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a [**question on REST**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication) a few days ago that yielded excellent feedback. Maybe some of it benefits you as well.

Comment: Very good discussion there. I am digesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes REST could definitely be used for this type of application.

However, be careful with the word transaction. If you mean transaction as in a "**database transaction** that can be automatically rolled back" then it is important to realize that those transactions should **sit behind the REST interface**.

If by transaction you mean "a series of steps that a user can choose to complete or cancel" then yes, REST can model those transactions as **additional resources**.

Comment: I mean the second thing. A series of steps user can choose to complete or cancel. Thanks.