# what should be HTTP status code if resource is not available for requested action?

Tags: api, rest, http, http-status-codes

I am developing a RESTful API. I am confused about setting HTTP status code in this particular scenario. I am not sure what status code should I (server) return.

Let's say my app has a follow user functionality, if I am already following a user and again I send follow request for the same user id then in this case what should be the HTTP status code from server. The status code will be followed by an error message saying something like: "already following the user."

Similar scenario can be considered for unfollow user functionality, if I am not following an user "A", still I send request to unfollow user "A", then what HTTP status code should server return with error message something like "not following user to unfollow"

Certainly 200 response code doesn't seem to be appropriate to me here? or does it?

Please forgive me if I have posted the question at wrong stack exchange site, I posted it in stackoverflow site just because it is related to REST APIs.

**EDIT**

From client side user needs to send POST request to the URL:

```
http://www.myserver.com/api/follow/10
```

along with other necessary parameters ( like API keys, proper headers, etc) which are used for authentication before serving the requests at server side.

similar URL for unfollow action is:

```
http://www.myserver.com/api/unfollow/10
```

Right now, I am sending HTTP status code 200 in response if the client sends follow request, let's say, for user id 10 even if he/she is already following the user with id 10. In this case,along with status code (200) I am sending message similar to "already following the user"

Somehow I feel this is not convincing as no resource is created/updated it should return the error message with proper status code something other than 200, may be one from 4XX, not sure.

Comment: Could you please add information about how you send these "follow" and "unfollow" requests? Because it sounds like you are using verbs in your URI, which would would not be very RESTful.

Comment: @Robert I have updated the question with information about follow/unfollow URI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 422 Unprocessable Entity

422 seems to be the proper HTTP status code in this use case.
The description of 422 says:

*The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.*

Comment: accepted this answer based on related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382163/974616

Comment: May I have a question that why the 409 conflict is not suitable?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your API. You're describing the API in terms of "follow user X" or "unfollow user Y". That makes me think you might be approaching your API design in an RPC style rather than focusing on resources.

If your API uses REST including the HATEOAS principle, then error codes from the 4xx range may be appropriate (but I would recommend against it in this case, see below). In very short: HATEOAS means that your resources provide links to possible "actions". You can read more about it here: http://restcookbook.com/Basics/hateoas/

Apart from that, it seems a good idea to design your API "fault tolerant", i.e. expect the same request sent multiple times (e.g. because users are impatient and click again and again, or the browser crashed and is restarted and reopens all previous tabs, or...).

My personal opinion and recommendation is the following:

- *follow user X*: Your implementation should check if it needs to add the new follower or not. Regardless, if the user is already following or not, send back HTTP status 201 (created) and add the "Location" HTTP header pointing at the resource.
- *unfollow user X*: Your implementation should check if it needs to delete the follower or not. Regardless, if the user is already removed from the followers or not, send back HTTP status 200 (OK).

The general idea is, if a client requests something to be a certain way and that is already the case, the server has two options: Either it responds to the client "The result you wish is already in place. Therefore your request is invalid." or the server can respond "The result you wish is already in place. You have everything you need.".
Going for the second option makes the API more tolerant and helps with idempotency (see http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will wait for a while before accepting your answer as "the accepted" answer, just to confirm it. 
as whether to send 200/201 against 4XX code was my primary confusion

Answer (score 1):

I think djlauk's answer covers a lot, but I want to give a little different approach and add some information:

### Do not use verbs in the URI

I would not use POST on `/follow/` respectively `/unfollow/` URIs because this is not very RESTful see this SO question: [Why does including an action verb in the URI in a REST implementation violate the protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173721/why-does-including-an-action-verb-in-the-uri-in-a-rest-implementation-violate-th) and escpacially this SO answer: [How to create REST URLs without verbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619152/how-to-create-rest-urls-without-verbs/1619677#1619677)

### Do use the correct HTTP verbs for the actions

What you want to do is a creation of an entity ("follow") so for that you can use the HTTP verbs [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) or [PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) and afterwards the deletion of that entity ("unfollow") where [DELETE](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) would be the right fit.

### My approach for your API:

I would do the following:

*(The first two examples are just for explaining the structure, you don't have to implement them if you don't need them.)*

---

This does get you the user "robert":

```
GET http://www.myserver.com/api/users/robert/
```

**response: `#200`**

---

This does get you the users "robert" is following:

```
GET http://www.myserver.com/api/users/robert/following/
```

**response: `#200`**

---

And this is how you let "robert" follow "rahul":

```
PUT http://www.myserver.com/api/users/robert/following/rahul
```

**response: `#200`**

If you send this request again you get the same response:**`#200`** because PUT is idempotent and this is how it should behave (see [(2)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6))

---

When you now want to let "robert" unfollow "rahul" you send:

```
DELETE http://www.myserver.com/api/users/robert/following/rahul
```

**response: `#200`**

If you send the DELETE request again you get a little different response a **`#404`** , but this is HTTP standard and the clients should understand this.

---

For the regular answer codes of HTTP methods I can also recommend this source: [restapitutorial.com](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use some of the following:

```
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

Better if it is one of the first two.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly 200 response code will not work in this situation.

following are the groups in HTTP Status Code:

- 1xx Informational
- 2xx Success
- 3xx Redirection
- 4xx Client Error
- 5xx Server Error

Certainly you need to use 4xx.

I think for the condition that you have described here, you can use any of the following:

### 405 Method Not Allowed

A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource; for example, using GET on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.

### 400 Bad Request

The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error

### 409 Conflict

Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the request, such as an edit conflict in the case of multiple updates.

More details are available here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: 405 - Method not allowed: I think it is not applicable here since method is available there and also sending the parameters in right format
400 - imho this is also not applicable "bad request" means request could not be understood by the server, which is not the case here
409- conflict status could be applicable here