# Jersey Jackson unmarshall JSON

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am working on an embedded jersey instance which will run a JAXB RESTful service.  I have configured Jackson with two steps:

1. Adding this to my POM

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>2.23.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Registering it in my application

   ```
   public HandheldApplication() {
   scripts.add(HandheldServer.class);
   scripts.add(BasicScript.class);
   // Add JacksonFeature.
   scripts.add(JacksonFeature.class);
   scripts.add(LoggingFilter.class);
   ```

   }

I have a complex object being passed back and forth as shown below:

```
package com.ziath.handheldserver.valueobjects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@XmlRootElement
public class Widget {

private String key;
private String name;
private List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
private String value;
private String type;

public Widget(){
    super();
}

public Widget(String key, String name, List<String> options, String value,
        String type) {
    super();
    this.key = key;
    this.name = name;
    this.options = options;
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<String> getOptions() {
    return options;
}
public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
    this.options = options;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

When I execute this in a GET method as shown below:

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("getKeys")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Widget> getKeys(@QueryParam(value = "page") int page)
```

This works fine and I get JSON back; however when I execute it is a PUT as shown below:

```
@Override
@PUT
@Path("validateKeys")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean validateKeys(@QueryParam(value = "page")int page, @QueryParam(value = "widgets")List<Widget> widgets)
```

When I execute a PUT to access this method I get a stack trace as follows:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ExtractorException: Error un-marshalling JAXB object of type: class com.ziath.handheldserver.valueobjects.Widget.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider$1.fromString(JaxbStringReaderProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.convert(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractParamValueExtractor.fromString(AbstractParamValueExtractor.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.CollectionExtractor.extract(CollectionExtractor.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.CollectionExtractor$ListValueOf.extract(CollectionExtractor.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.QueryParamValueFactoryProvider$QueryParamValueFactory.provide(QueryParamValueFactoryProvider.java:89)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider$1.fromString(JaxbStringReaderProvider.java:190)
    ... 43 more
```

So it seems to me that Jackson is correctly *marshalling* my POJO into JSON but trying to *unmarshall* it as XML.  Note that I switched to Jackson away from MOXy because I needed to be able to handle collections coming back and forth and apparently MOXy cannot do that.

Is there a setting I've missed to tell Jackson/Jersey to go both ways for JSON?

Comment: How are you executing the PUT? From javascript, a command line, a JAX-RS client, or something else?

Comment: Sorry; I found the answer the problem was that Jackson/Jersey automatically marshalls a POJO into JSON but doesn't unmarshall it so I needed to remove the XML related annotation at the top and manually put in a fromString method to unmarhsall JSON into the object.

Comment: Jersey definitely can unmarshall entities from the body as well. I suspect you were not supplying the proper Content-Type header (application/json) when making the request, which is why I was wondering how you were invoking it (when I `curl` from the command line, I often forget the `-H 'Content-Type: application/json`).

Comment: Hello - no the problem was that I needed to provide a unmarshall method for the object - see my own answer.  The correct content type was provided but it could not automatically unmarshall the JSON without a helper method - the helper method fromString is sought by Jersey/Jackson and it all works just fine.  Now I have provided the unmarshall method it works just fine.  Thanks for taking the time to comment however.

Comment: I suspect you could've done it without a static fromString method and without a @FormParam. But it sounds like your solution works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was switching between QueryParam and FormParam to try and get one of them to work.  If I  use FormParam I  also need to change the consumes to APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.

The actual issue was that the default unmarshalling with Jackson was using XML because it was tagged as an XML resource - take that out! I finally managed to work out how to unmarshall from JSON by using a static fromString method.  Then to handle the list; I cannot use a wrapper class because this needs to be highly cross language and exposing a wrapper with a list would have complicated the implementation from Python, C#, etc.  The way to get it to accept a list with a wrapper is to post the name of the param (in this case widgets) multiple time.  Then each JSON passed in will be called against the fromString method.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `@QueryParam(value = "widgets")` because you should pass it as entity body - not query param.

```
@PUT
@Path("validateKeys")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean validateKeys(@QueryParam(value = "page")int page, List<Widget> widgets)
```

Also you can make wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Widgets {

    private List<Widget> widgets; 

    // other fields, setters and getters
}
```

And then:

```
@PUT
@Path("validateKeys")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean validateKeys(@QueryParam(value = "page")int page, Widgets widgets)
```

I would suggest to read some discussions about REST design because you're using verbs in your paths:

- [Is this a bad REST URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208405/is-this-a-bad-rest-url?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Understanding REST: Verbs, error codes, and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication)

Comment: Thanks I posted the answer above and thanks for the REST grammar; I autogenerated the code stubs at first which I'll clean up later when going into deployment.