# web api single custom routing for all actions

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, routes, url-routing

I have five actions in my web api controller as follows.

`http://localhost:1234/products` - to map `getallproduct` action
`http://localhost:1234/products/1` - to map `getproductnyid` action
`http://localhost:1234/products` - `saveproduct` action (post)
`http://localhost:1234/products/1/getcolor` - `getproductcolorbyid` action
`http://localhost:1234/products/1/getcost` - `getproductcostbyid` action

I need **only one** custom routing url for this.

I have tried following routing but it appends action name in url(`http://localhost:24007/product/GetProductByID/Id`) which i don't want.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ProductRoute",
    routeTemplate: "product/{action}/{productId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", productId= RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Attribute Routing if you want this kind of flexibility:

```
[RoutePrefix("products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProduct()
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{productId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductById(int id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{productId}/getcolor")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductColorById(int id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{productId}/getcost")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductCostById(int id)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And remember to register them in your `HttpConfiguration` object:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

---

As an aside: if you are designing a RESTful API (which it seems to me) I strongly suggest you to avoid using RPC-like actions in your URIs (e.g. never use URI segments like `getcolor`, `getcost`), but use names that conforms with REST constraints:

```
http://localhost:1234/products/1/color
http://localhost:1234/products/1/cost
```

This can be achieved by changing your `RouteAttribute`s:

```
[Route("{productId}/color")]
//...
[Route("{productId}/cost")]
```

Comment: Thanks. As per the requirement we should not use attribute routing

Comment: I'm afraid you have no other options then.

Comment: Can you please explain why should not use urls like getcolors,getcost?

Comment: Any RESTful URI should only represent a resource. Actions on that resource (verbs, intents, etc.) should only be expressed using HTTP Methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646989/is-using-a-verb-in-url-fundamentally-incompatible-with-rest) may be useful, also [this resource](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) could help furhter clarify REST APIs URI design methods.