# can we have multiple http method in single resource in API gateway in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, devops

I am trying my hands with API Gateways in AWS.

[image]

Both these methods have **same API end point**. By default it is calling lambda function set for GET method.

I feel i missed a trick here somewhere.

Should i create a different Resource for PUT method or we have it in same resource with different api end point ?

Comment: @Nicholas Sizer

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to this you could use the `ANY` method but you will become responsible in your Lambda for interpreting how you handle any method you do not want to support.

> You can set up the ANY method on a non-proxy resource as well. Combining the ANY method with a proxy resource, you get a single API method setup for all of the supported HTTP methods against any resources of an API. Furthermore, the backend can evolve without breaking the existing API setup.

More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html#setup-method-add-http-method).

Comment: i am just starting out with all this API and gateway this . It is hard me to understand most of the thing.

what i am trying is i need to use PUT , DELETE , PATCH  methods .

"call" is the resource here so i was thinking to have all these methods with in them with different end point.
but 
the same end point is being auto populated is there a way to change the end point or should i create a new resource.