# Using RESTler, can I name a method something different than post() or postSomething() when it must accept arguments via an HTTP post?

Tags: php, restler

I'm considering using Lucarast RESTler (http://luracast.com/products/restler/)

My PHP class has a method called 'solve' and it must accept an argument via POST

```
class Solver
{
  function solve( $request_data )
  {
    ...
  }
```

If I simply name the method "solve", it can't be accessed via POST. I get 404.

```
POST http://localhost/path/to/my/method 404 (Not Found)
```

Apparently I have to name it "postSolve", that works. Or create another method called "postSolve" that simply calls "solve".

```
public function postSolve( $request_data )
{
    return $this->solve( $request_data );
}
```

But I can't stop thinking there must be an elegant way of doing this.

How can I call my method whatever I want, and still make it accessible via POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned a bit more about REST in the past few days.
I shouldn't be needing methods called anything other than get, post, put, or delete.

Please refer to this other question:
[Understanding REST: Verbs, error codes, and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication)

> "In general, when you think you need more verbs, it may actually mean
>   that your resources need to be re-identified. Remember that in REST
>   you are always acting on a resource, or on a collection of resources.
>   What you choose as the resource is quite important for your API
>   definition."

Answer (score 2):

Auto routing requires you to prefix the api method names with `get` or `post` or `put` or `delete` to map it to the respective HTTP method/verb

More on this at this [example](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_007_crud/readme.html)

But you can always use a PHPDoc comment in the following format above the api method to map any method to POST

`@url POST my/custom/url/:myvar`

For example

```
class CustomPost
{
    /**
     * @url POST custom/:id
     * @url GET custom
     */
    function anyName($id)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```