# PUT method with @FormParam

Tags: java, json, rest, put, form-parameter

If I have something like:

```
@PUT
@Path("/login")
@Produces({"application/json", "text/plain"})
@Consumes("application/json")
public String login(@FormParam("login") String login, @FormParam("password") String password) throws Exception
{
    String response = null;
    response = new UserManager().login(login, password);
    return response;
}
```

How can I enter the both parameters to Test my REST services (in the Content field)? 
Isn't something like:

```
{"login":"xxxxx","password":"xxxxx"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form parameter data will only be present when you submit ... form data. Change the `@Consumes` type for your resource to `multipart/form-data`.

```
@PUT
@Path("/login")
@Produces({ "application/json", "text/plain" })
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public String login(@FormParam("login") String login,
        @FormParam("password") String password) {
    String response = null;
    response = new UserManager().login(login, password);
    return response;
}
```

Then on your client side, set:

- Content-Type: multipart/form-data
- Add form variables for `login` and `password`

On a side note, assuming this isn't for learning, you will want to secure your login endpoint with SSL, and hash the password before sending it across the wire.

---

***EDIT***

Based on your comment, I am including an example of sending a client request with the required form data:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(BASE_URI + "/services/users/login");

    // Setup form data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "blive1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
            "d30a62033c24df68bb091a958a68a169"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

    // Check response status and read data
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Something like:

`HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(BASE_URI + "/services.users/login");`
`Form f = new Form();
 f.add("login", "xxxxx");
 f.add("password", "xxxxx");` ??

Comment: @user2144555 - See edits for a viable way to call the server resource, using Apache HttpComponents.

Comment: I was using Apache HttpClient too. But I was thinking that " **form variables for login and password** " were send in a different way. I will try that!

Comment: Thanks, it's working!
But I was initially asking how to enter those parameters in the TEST RESTful WEB SERVICES main page. Do you know what I'm talking about? It's their main page.

Comment: Whats the link of the page you are talking about?

Comment: C:\Users\Ines\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LULServices\build\generated-sources\rest-test\test-resbeans.html

Comment: I would guess that to be a Netbeans auto-generated test page for your web service. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Netbeans could detect the invalid combination of annotations on your resource method.

Comment: Sorry, another question about the @FormParam: they can be used with PUTs? I'm always doing PUTs instead of POSTs. Is that a problem?

Comment: You should only do PUT's for operations that will be updating an entity. Actually, each one of the HTTP verbs maps to a specific RESTful operation, and you should try to use them appropriately. You can read [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2022938/680925), which gives a nice summary of what to use when.

Comment: Yes, I'm always doing updates. But i read that "HTML forms are an easy means of getting information from a user and they are also easy to create. Form data can be used for HTTP GET requests and HTTP POST requests." That's why I was asking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26660/discussion-between-perception-and-user2144555)