# java rest web services - side effect of using get instead of post

Tags: java, rest, web-services

What is the side effect of using get method in java rest web service instead of post or put or delete? I know I have to use get for retrieving data and post for saving. But, what if I used get instead?

Comment: Well, GET doesn't allow to send a request body (to submit values). That would be quite a problem. But even if you passed them in the query string, any proxy or browser would be free to send the request multiple times on your behalf, because it expects a GET to be idempotent. A POST is not idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you will probably going against the design. There are many good discussion here and below are few references,

1. [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
2. [REST API using POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637459/rest-api-using-post-instead-of-get)
3. [REST: Can I use POST request to read data?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313715/rest-can-i-use-post-request-to-read-data)