# Secure way to send a mail via a (Restful) Webservice

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, email

I have a AngularJS Webapplication with Java Backend.

Now i want to send a mail out of the Angular Application. I thought the best way is to send a post or get request to the webservice and send the Mail via an internal smtp server to the recipient.

But i think there is a big security problem with this concept. When i create a webservice call like: `/api/mail?mailto=john@doe.com` someone can take the link to the webservice, change the recipient and take this link to start spamming to other people.

Do someone know a secure way for this architecture to send a mail via a webservice? It is necessary that i have to pass the recipient to the mail service, because the user set this in the AngularJS UI.

I am happy about any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the security measures you should take for securing your rest api.
 [REST Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet)
Here is the list of security measures you should take for your rest API.

- **HTTPS**
- **Access Control** - For access control, you can API keys, OAuth, etc. take a look at this article https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way
- **Restrict HTTP methods** - Can be handled in controller.
- **Security headers** - Use proper security header to prevent CORS, CSRF attack. (*The attack you specified in your question*). Have look in this article https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html.
- **Pass Sensitive information in HTTP POST request**

If you use **[spring-security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)** you will be covered in most of this.

Comment: The webservice is the backend for a public webapplication. How can i put an authentication on it without asking for credentials or without to put a application hash or something like that into the javascript code?

Comment: Are you saying that your web service is public and has no security measures?

Comment: I think i am using the most common thing to secure the webservice: HTTPS, CORS Header, Restrict HTTP Methods, Type safe parameters... But all this dont prevent an Attacker to take the link and start spamming as i described at the top. But thank you for the link. I will have a look on CSRF. But i am not sure if this will prevent the attack i described.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). You can send 10,000 emails for free you can call the API via your Java backend, like so:

```
public static ClientResponse SendSimpleMessage() {
    Client client = Client.create();
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(
        "api","key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"));
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/messages");
    MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    formData.add("from", "Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>");
    formData.add("to", "john@doe.com");
    formData.add("subject", "Hello");
    formData.add("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!");
    return webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).
        post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
}
```

This would be more secure than your implementation. I would also send the email address from the Angular client to your Java backend as a POST.

Comment: Where is the difference if is send the mail to an external mail server or internal? I think there is no difference. But i already thought about it to send the mail address as POST. But i think in the browser network tab i can see the API call to and an attacker can reproduce it...

Comment: That might be because you are running off localhost if you are running it locally. Maybe take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637459/rest-api-using-post-instead-of-get)