# Postback cause browser confirmation before refreshing (F5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

When I do a `postback`, why the browser always ask me a confirmation before refreshing ? (F5 / CTRL + F5)

My code is really simple (I use a master page) :

.aspx

```
...
<asp:button runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" type="button" id="btnlogin" 
                  OnClientClick="return veriflogin();" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Valider" 
                  onclick="btnlogin_Click"></asp:button>

<asp:Label ID="ok" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="allright"></asp:Label>
...
```

.cs

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ok.Visible = true;
}
```

The confirmation (IE):

[image]

Can I avoid this confirmation ?

Comment: When you refresh that page, you execute the Postback again. This message warns about potential problems with that. See also [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: the browser does that automatically, it's normal behavior

Comment: You can't avoid this confirmation because its managed by your browser itself. Like Jonesy said its normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postback occurs (as name suggests) using `POST` HTTP verb.  `POST` [by definition is not idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), and thus repeating the same request is not necessarily safe.  In other words, repeating `POST` may result in different end result than doing it once.  Hence the browser warns you that in order to retrieve the page again, it has to repeat `POST` operation which may have unintended consequences.

For example, in [RESTful applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication), `POST` implies "create" (as in CRUD, akin to SQL's `INSERT`) a resource.  Executing `POST` twice means two instances of the resource will be created rather than one.  Compare it with `GET` which is a read operation, and reading the same resource more than once does not affect the state of the resource(s), and is thus considered safe (because `GET` is idempotent)

Comment: So can I make my button click to use GET method to avoid this ?

Comment: @VincP. buttons that calls back to the server are per definition postbacks. You should probably rethink how you want to authenticate the user.

Comment: @VincP. IIRC (been awhile), ASP.NET WebForms uses one single form and any action that causes callback to server must submit the form (so all the form state is passed in with the request) and the form is `POST`. If instead of rendering the form back, you can do `.Redirect` (which browser follows up on with a `GET`), then this should remove that warning (but there are implications since viewstate is lost).  But I hope others can lend a better suggestion as it's been a long while ago since I did WebForms.

Comment: Ty, I agree, postback = post. I forgot that. Now it is clear. Ty for the suggestion. But I was wondering if I could do something, but it look like I can't ! (With this method)

Comment: @VincP. This is a login form, right?  After user is authenticated, how do you transfer user to the next page?  Can you transition via `.Redirect`?  If so, this may do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I will probably do that. But I wanted to understand why the browser ask a confirmation. It will be useful to understand how it works. TY

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't avoid the confirmation.

If your last action on a site was a POST, most browsers will ask for a confirmation on whether you want to refresh the site with the same POST again. That's intended behavior.

POST requests are intended to modify state in one way or another. That's why your browser warns you. GET requests should not modify state, and are therefore considered "safe" to resubmit.