# Making a Rails Route as PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a Rails 4 route as below. This defaults to a GET route. How do I make it a PUT? I'm using this route for in-place form editing but the edits don't save in the database. I'm not sure if making this a PUT is the solution but wanted to try it out. Is there a way to get the same route be a GET and PUT?

```
get 'orderupdate' => "orders#update"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the method from `get` to `put`:

```
put 'orderupdate' => "orders#update"
```

Also, [be sure to use your HTTP verbs correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022938/2498956).

Answer (score 0):

***You should uses put/patch verb for updating*** so you can change your route to use both of them by

```
match 'orderupdate', to: "orders#update", via: [:put, :patch]
```

Instead of using ***individual routes like this, i'll recommend you to use rails resourceful routes by:***

```
resources :orders
```

*which will automatically create [`crud routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for you*