# Is this a RESTful way to handle multiple verbs for a resource?

Tags: web-services, rest, http-post

I am attempting to write a Restful API to control a CMS.  There are `Objects` (e.g., An instance of an `Article`) and each object has multiple `Draft`s.  To work on an object's `Draft`s, I built a URL like this:

```
/cms/objects/{objectId}/drafts/{draftId}
```

`draftId`s are not unique unless you provide an `objectId`.

Hopefully I haven't already messed up with this.  But now I have multiple verbs I want to perform on each `Draft`.  Here's a list of verbs:

```
CLONE, UNPUBLISH, PUBLISH, UNLOCK, LOCK
```

The way I approached this is to create an endpoint that has an `operation` query param.  And here's an example of how you use it:

```
POST /cms/objects/3232/drafts/1?operation=CLONE
POST /cms/objects/3232/drafts/1?operation=LOCK
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm actually upgrading an already existing API, and the way you used to do something like this is like so:

```
POST cms/objects/3232/duplicate-draft?source-draft-id=1
POST cms/objects/3232/lock?draft-id=1
```

I prefer my way, because in my eyes it's more consistent (though I am biased).  Is there a better way to do this?

---

By the way, I am aware of [this question that is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication).  The reason I'm creating this new one is that mine is laser focused on the "multiple verb" aspect and his isn't.  His is more like, "how do I do multiple verbs and can you teach me lots of other stuff about Restful APIs, too?"

Also, I feel that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022938/61624) on that question does not sufficiently address this (see his point 2).  For example, my `Draft`s, do not have a `lock=true` in their body so I can't easily map the advice from his **Change Password** section.  My `Draft`s have two fields to represent if the `Draft` is locked: The user name of the locker and the user id of the locker.  It would be inconvenient to have the client pass these both in so my intent above is to abstract that work away from the client.

Comment: If it were me I would explore moving lock and clone to it's own service. Having a lock on and a clone service allows you to separate that functionality from the object and keeps your url syntax cleaner. You could POST to /clone/object_id , or DELETE /lock/object_id.

Comment: @dudeman ok, what do I do with the draft id?  You clone/lock a `draft`, not an `object`.

Comment: I think I just mixed your metaphors. In my mind I was thinking of the argument those services would accept as being generic. So, my syntax /lock/object could also mean: be /lock/draft, /lock/comment, /lock/object. I'm not sure if that would require you to provide users with a type parameter, /log/object?type=draft. Not loving that. But, worth exploring the idea I guess.