# What is difference between action based and resource base URI ?

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

*I just start exploring about RESTful services, and i find rest uses resource based URI so i just wanted to know what is the difference between them and is there resource based URI has any advantage over action based URI     *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding REST: Verbs, error codes, and authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication)

Answer (score 9):

## Action-based URLs:

- Focus on the action being performed
- Usually include a verb
- Often rely on external sources to identify the resource being acted on (e.g., session state)

## Resource-based URLs:

- Focus on the resource being acted on
- Usually consist of nouns
- Rely on HTTP verbs to define the action being performed (e.g., GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE)

## Examples:

```
Action-based URL                     Resource-based URL
-----------------------------------------------------------------
GET  /register                       GET    /accounts/application
POST /register                       POST   /accounts
GET  /catalog/search                 GET    /queries/form
POST /catalog/search                 POST   /queries
GET  /cart                           GET    /order/123
POST /cart/add-item                  POST   /order/123/items
POST /cart/empty                     DELETE /order/123
GET  /check-out                      GET    /order/123/invoice
POST /check-out                      POST   /order/123/payments
GET  /thank-you                      GET    /order/123/receipt
POST /sign-in                        POST   /sessions
POST /admin/delete-user?id=123       DELETE /user/123
GET  /catalog/edit?id=123            GET    /items/123/form
POST /catalog/edit?id=123            PUT    /items/123
```