# what exactly is a RESTful resource web api?

Tags: ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-5

Im new to web programming, and im starting out with Ruby on Rails. Im having trouble grasping the concept of RESTful resources or web API or URI. Can someone please explain to me in a simple term that i could understand?

Comment: In Rails a Restful resource is a Model (the M in MVC) that can be manipulated by the client/user in a RESTful manner.

Comment: Here's another [REST explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication).