# RESTfully creating singleton resource

Tags: rest, api-design

Most examples of RESTful APIs assume you are dealing with collections of things, e.g.

`POST /books/` - create a book

`GET /books/`  - get a list of books

`GET /books/1/` - get a particular book

However, there are some circumstances where you might want to create a singleton resource. For example, a new user might want to create a profile relating to themselves, the authenticated user.

`POST /profile`

`PUT /profile`

Is there any convention about how to create such singleton resources? i.e. using `POST` vs `PUT`. In terms of whether to use `POST` or `PUT`, does it make a difference if the resource can be modified after creation? Does the idempotency requirement of `PUT` require that it must be possible to update the resource after it is first created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication?rq=1

Comment: you can find the detail in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in REST a "singleton" resource doesn't mean there's only one instance of the resource in the system, it just means retrieving a single object rather than a list of objects.

> A resource can be a singleton or a collection. For example, “customers” is a collection resource and “customer” is a singleton resource (in a banking domain). We can identify “customers” collection resource using the URN “/customers”. We can identify a single “customer” resource using the URN “/customers/{customerId}”.
>
> <sub>(Thoughtworks, [Rest API Design: Resource Modeling](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling))</sub>

Standard practice would be for the client to `POST` to `/profiles`/, receiving the URL of the newly created profile (probably `/profiles/<id>`) in the `Location:` header of the response.

Alternatively, the client could `PUT` to `/profiles/<some client-specified-ID>`, receiving `403 Forbidden` if the ID is already taken by another user. (Possibly [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5), if the other user's profile would be `GET`-able.)

On the reading side, it's not common to model the concept of "my profile", with an unknown ID, in a RESTful API. If you really need it, probably the RESTful thing to do is advertise the (identified) URL in a link from the root resource, with a custom link relation.