# Insert multiple values to an API query

Tags: xml, rest, api, postman

i´m pretty new and unexpirenced at API´s. I´m using postman to get some seluts from a database.

https://www.website.com/xmlapi/api.php?cid=abc&auth=123456&command=product&model={{model}}

I´ve created the value of the key model as a variable. Now I want to get more than 1 result from the API for ex. 5 Values:

123456
654321
987456
253698
521251

How can I include this list of values into postman?

I also have a csv file for upload.

I want to get back one xml file with all values of the key model.

Can anybody help?

Best regards
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I've imagine you are going to send a GET request.You can include necessary API parameters in your API call,If it is a Post request you may use model class to get a xml back. Also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication?rq=1)

See below example :

```
  [HttpGet("number-count/{Num1}/{Num2}/{Num3}/{Num4}/{Num5}/")]
        public ActionResult GetNumberData(int Num1, int Num2, int Num3, int Num4, int Num5)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_service.GetNumberConsumption(Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4,Num5));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return NoContent();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks PrathapG! I´m working with postma. Where should I include your example?