# REST endpoints using verbs or nouns

Tags: rest

so i need to create a rest endpoint that basically creates an entry in the database, a address token when the customer is initialised. I have two possible endpoints:

POST  -  customer/address-token   -  this creates a address for a user

POST  - customer/initialise   -

im thinking should i use the former or latter? I have read a few topics on this, whereby the latter is a termed a controller resource type?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it already has an answer here:  [Understanding REST: Verbs, error codes, and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001773/understanding-rest-verbs-error-codes-and-authentication) .  To summarize, the REST architecture style is to avoid verbs in URLs, so your first form is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the first form is better and more intuitive to know what are do.

POST - customer/address-token - this creates a address for a user